# extract values with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have a json object deserialized and I like to extract the data from 2 fields, **openbareRuimteNaam** and **woonplaatsNaam**.

I've created the following class:

```
Public Class Adres
    Public Property openbareRuimteNaam As String
    Public Property woonplaatsNaam As String
End Class
```

Then I call

`Dim account As Adres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Adres)(json.last.value.ToString)`

It comes back empty.

What am I missing? Did try a lot of google suggestions but it all comes back negative.
Please help me out here

Thanks
Knelis

the json.last.value =

```
{
  ""adressen"": [
    {
      ""openbareRuimteNaam"": ""Diemerkade"",
      ""korteNaam"": ""Diemerkade"",
      ""huisnummer"": 1,
      ""postcode"": ""1111AA"",
      ""woonplaatsNaam"": ""Diemen"",
      ""nummeraanduidingIdentificatie"": ""0384200000002229"",
      ""openbareRuimteIdentificatie"": ""0384300000000042"",
      ""woonplaatsIdentificatie"": ""2144"",
      ""adresseerbaarObjectIdentificatie"": ""0384010000001685"",
      ""pandIdentificaties"": [
        ""0384100000005380""
      ],
      ""adresregel5"": ""Diemerkade 1"",
      ""adresregel6"": ""1111 AA  DIEMEN"",

}
```

Comment: Your json is for a root object that has an array ("adressen") as well as a couple of additional fields.  You need to update your VB-side class definition accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim account As Adres = JObject.Parse((json.last.value.ToString))
                              ("adressen")(0).ToObject(Of Adres)()
```